# Which form of Authentication should I use?

Tags: authentication, authorization

I'm writing a Web API for my users to access their information on my site. However, I'm not sure what type of authentication I should use for such a task.

Here are my intentions:

One of my users develops an app that needs information on their account from my server. He sends me a key and I verify that he's a valid user.

There shouldn't be any 'middle-man' apps that are doing anything on the user's behalf. Just the owner of the account. Currently, I'm using a system where I hash a GUID and the user sends that string to me. I decrypt it, and check my database for that key.

I'm not sure what this method is called, but it seems to work. Does anyone have a better solution that I could use that (probably) better uses web standards?

Answer (score 0):

This question screams: OAuth.

http://oauth.net/2/

More details:

> OAuth is an authentication protocol that allows you to approve one
>   application interacting with another on your behalf **without giving
>   away your password**.

Taken from: http://blog.varonis.com/introduction-to-oauth/

Comment: Not really, I don't want the user to have to authorize an app on my site. I simply want to hand him a key and let him use it to access my API. I'd just like to do it more securely than I do now.

Comment: In that case, why don't you just write a Web Service and only allow an external app that uses an exclusive SSL client Certificate to consume the WSDL?

Comment: Isn't this (essentially) what I'm already doing? Hashing a random value that the user then sends back through an HTTPS header?

Comment: Dude, haven't you heard of replay attacks? Mallet doesn't need to decrypt your request in order to impersonate your app... NSA will really enjoy your web API :)

Comment: Is SSL not enough to avoid replay attacks?

Comment: " I'm using a system where I hash a GUID and the user sends that string to me" -- this is not enough, let's not reinvent the wheel and create our own encryption algorithm. Yes, SSL+HTTP communication would be a good practice in this case, e.g., Kerberos uses timestamps in 2 back and forth interactions, so it prevents replay attacks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62836/discussion-between-nyx-and-themarcelor).